# VB.NET MS PowerPoint Slide Background

Tags: vb.net, powerpoint

I'm currently working with PowerPoint in VB.NET and having a bit of trouble getting a slide to have an individual background. Using the SlideMaster method changes all slide in the presentation and I want only one to be affected can anyone offer any advice? I'm not in a position to post code at the moment, but I will comment with some when I can, if no one can help.

PS Using the Background.Fill.UserPicture method doesn't seem to be working, but I'm not sure why...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sometimes the macro recorder in older versions is a blessing, in its own odd way.  Here's what PPT 2003 gives you when you record the act of setting a background to a picture for a given slide (after I've commented out the bits that don't have much/any effect on things):

```
With ActiveWindow.Selection.SlideRange
    .FollowMasterBackground = msoFalse
    '.DisplayMasterShapes = msoTrue
    With .Background
        .Fill.Visible = msoTrue
        '.Fill.ForeColor.RGB = RGB(255, 255, 255)
        '.Fill.BackColor.SchemeColor = ppAccent1
        '.Fill.Transparency = 0#
        .Fill.UserPicture "C:\Documents and Settings\Me\My Documents\My Pictures\photo.jpg"
    End With
End With
```

UserPicture is the way to set the picture fill, as you see here; but you have to set .FollowMasterBackground to False, else it ignores your fill settings.

Comment: Thanks very much for this! I've only just come back to the project, having had exams to do, but I forgot to stop it following the master, works perfectly now.